# What are the methodological differences between a ‘constructed’ and a ‘standardized’ psychological test?

Tags: measurement

What are the methodological differences between a ‘constructed’ and a ‘standardized’ psychological test?

This was a question asked in the exam. Kindly help me understand the key differences.

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE. Please visit the site [tour] where after reading in full, you recieve a badge.  We work differently to most SE sites, where we have a strict policy that all questions should [show evidence of prior research](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/993). Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Comment: Welcome. What did you find so far? We're not here to do your homework, but we're glad to help to assist in complementing the answer you have constructed so far.

Comment: I'm not sure this is even a valid contrast... 'standardized' tests are also 'constructed'. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standardized_test

Comment: As for test construction methods https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_construction_strategies I guess the contrast intended to be made is between standardized and ad-hoc test; e.g. teacher- or psychologist-made https://www.britannica.com/science/psychological-testing/Written-group-versus-oral-individual-tests#ref23858

Answer (score 0):

A standardized test is one that is given in a consistent manner and yields the same, valid, results each time. Students are administered the test in the same environment and given the same amount of time. A constructed test would then be the opposite; takers are given different amounts of time, administered the test in different environments and evaluated differently.